# What are C++11 atomic classes?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, atomic

I would like to know what are "C++11 atomic classes" that GCC-4.7.2 talks of in [the 4.7 changelog](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html). I have tried Googling but didn't get any useful information on this. Does this mean that all operations are atomic so the class is thread-safe and operations are linearizable?

Comment: -1: [Second hit on Google for "C++ atomic".](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic)

Comment: *"I have tried Googling"* - No, you didn't! *"but didn't get any useful information on this"* - Yes, you did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic):

> The atomic library provides components for fine-grained atomic operations allowing for lockless concurrent programming.

So in short yes all operations on an atomic variable are, well, atomic, and therefore threadsafe.